# How to hide MvxListView local:MvxItemTemplate linear layout in MVVMCross Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

We are trying use MVX binding for visibility in view model for template linear layout but it won't work in our case as visibility works in main.axml but not works template, please us if anything we are missing with that
see below are some code snippet

```
Main.axml    

<MvvmCross.DroidX.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/mvx_list_basket"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
                            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource BasketObsList;ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand"
                            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/_itemtemplate"/>
            



_itemtemplate.axml            
                            
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LayoutScheduleExist"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(IsScheduleExist)">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                local:MvxBind="Text ScheduleName"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                local:MvxBind="Text LabelDiscount"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And the Visibility plugin is installed? Do you see any warnings in the debug output about bindings?

Comment: visibility plugin working but its not working in template, we uses that in most of the pages ....

Answer (score 0):

Provide full content of the _itemtemplate.axml.

P.S. You can use "local:MvxBind="**Visible IsScheduleExist**"" for simplicity

Comment: same thing we are doing but only having issue while accessing from template, main page it works fine.

Comment: What items does BasketObsList contain?

Comment: That list contained items data like name, price & quantity